# How to Calculate the Product of Summations

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

Let $X_1, \dots X_n \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu, \mathbb{V}[X_i] = \sigma^2, \mu\in\mathbb{R}, \sigma^2 > 0, \mathbb{E}[(X_i)^4] < \infty.$

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \sum_{l=1}^n X_l \right]\\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[(X_i)^4 \right] + 4\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{l\neq i}^n\mathbb{E}\left[(X_i)^3X_l \right] + 3\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i}^n\mathbb{E}\left[(X_i)^2(X_j)^2 \right]\\ + 6\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i}^n \sum_{k\neq i,j}^n\mathbb{E}\left[(X_i)^2 X_j X_k \right] + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i}^n \sum_{k\neq i,j}^n \sum_{l\neq i,j,k}^n \mathbb{E}\left[X_i X_j X_k X_l \right]
$$

In the expansion of this equation, $4$, $3$ and $6$ appear in the coefficients, but I do not know how to find these coefficients.

Comment: Writing it without the "$-\mu$" will make it much easier.

Comment: Try $n=2$, you may probably see the reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try.

Comment: But is there any way to lead immediately using combination C, etc.?

Comment: By independence, you will reach that $E(X_i^2X_jX_k ) = E(X_i^2)E(X_j)E(X_k) = E(X_i^2) \mu^2,$ etc. At some point, you can use $E(X_i^2) = \sigma^2 + \mu^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are related to partitions:

- $4=1\times 4+0\times3+0\times 2+0\times 1$ so $\frac{4!}{(4!^1 3!^0 2!^0 1!^0)(1!0!0!0!)} =1$ for $x_i^4$
- $4=0\times 4+1\times3+0\times 2+1\times 1$ so $\frac{4!}{(4!^0 3!^1 2!^0 1!^1)(0!1!0!1!)} =4$ for $x_i^3x_j$
- $4=0\times 4+0\times3+2\times 2+0\times 1$ so $\frac{4!}{(4!^0 3!^0 2!^2 1!^0)(0!0!2!0!)} =3$ for $x_i^2x_j^2$
- $4=0\times 4+0\times3+1\times 2+2\times 1$ so $\frac{4!}{(4!^0 3!^0 2!^1 1!^2)(0!0!1!2!)} =6$ for $x_i^2x_jx_k$
- $4=0\times 4+0\times3+0\times 2+4\times 1$ so $\frac{4!}{(4!^0 3!^0 2!^0 1!^4)(0!0!0!4!)} =1$ for $x_ix_jx_kx_l$